# Static factory method at EJB

Tags: java, jsf, interface, ejb

I have an EJB which I don't want anyone to be able to instantiate explicitly. So I have a static method for instantiating it( Factory method) this class is called EmailEJB. It has an interface called EmailService.

Now as I am using jsf, I have a managed bean called EmailMB.

My questions:

1. Why do I have access only to the interface and not to the bean itself?
2. How can I instantiate that EmailEJB in EmailMB ? I cannot have an static class inside interface and I cannot instantiate interface.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An EJB is instanciated and its lifecycle is managed by your container.

A Managed Bean is linked to JSF and supposed to contains values from your user.

The role of the EJB is to execute the business job (retrieve data from database, save, update, insert, call another EJB, etc...).

You extract informations from your managed bean and give them to a method of your EJB as parameters. The EJB will do the job and maybe give you some information back which can be stored in the managed bean to go back to the user.

The EJB will never be instanciated in a managed bean. **You don't manage the EJB : it is managed by the application server**.

Comment: Thanks, I ll try what you said and will get back.